# Code does not change the random COM value after 5 guesses

Tags: python, counter

I am trying to make this code say "You Guessed 5 Number. Computer Generated A New Number." and change the value of COM after 5 guesses that the user made.

Nothing changed after creating a count value. It was not triggered!

```
import random

class Emo:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.com = random.randint(1, x)
        self.number = 0
        self.count = 0

    def dos(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.number = int(input("Try Another One: \n"))
        number = self.number
        com = self.com
        if number < com:
            print("Higher")
            self.dos()
        elif number > com:
            print("Lower")
            self.dos()
        else:
            print("Correct!! You won.\n"
                  "\n"
                  "~旦_(^O^ )\n"
                  "")
            one_more = input("Want to play one more time? (e/h)\n")
            if one_more == "e":
                Emo(100).uno()  # Restart the code
            else:
                print("\nThanks For Playing :) ")
                exit()

    def uno(self):
        while self.com != self.number:
            number = int(input(f"Guess a number between 1 and {self.x}: \n"))
            com = self.com

            if number < com:
                print("Higher")
                self.dos()
            elif number > com:
                print("Lower")
                self.dos()
            else:
                print("Correct!! You won..\n"
                      "\n"
                      "~旦_(^O^ )\n"
                      "")
                one_more = input("Want to play one more time? (e/h)\n")
                if one_more == "e":
                    Emo(100).uno()  # Restart the code
                else:
                    print("\nThanks For Playing :)")
                    exit()

            if self.count == 5:
                self.com = random.randint(1, self.x)
                print("You Guessed 5 Number. Computer Generated A New Number.")
                self.count = 0


Emo(100).uno()
```

Comment: The function uno doesn't return anything!!!  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: This line `Emo(100).uno()  # Restart the code` **does not** restart the code. It recurses into the same function.

Comment: Your code has several issues. 1) Potential for infinite recursion, 2) doesn't properly check against number of guesses, 3) Unnecessary complexity from duplicating logic across two functions.

Comment: How to solve it then?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is immediately skipping to `self.dos()` after a guess, it doesn't reach the conditional statement for checking if above 5 guesses. You would fix this by moving the count check up like so:

```py
def uno(self):
        while self.com != self.number:
            number = int(input(f"Guess a number between 1 and {self.x}: \n"))
            com = self.com

            if self.count == 5:
                self.com = random.randint(1, self.x)
                print("You Guessed 5 Number. Computer Generated A New Number.")
                self.count = 0

            if number < com:
                print("Higher")
                self.dos()
            elif number > com:
                print("Lower")
                self.dos()
            else:
                print("Correct!! You won..\n"
                      "\n"
                      "~旦_(^O^ )\n"
                      "")
                one_more = input("Want to play one more time? (e/h)\n")
                if one_more == "e":
                    Emo(100).uno()  # Restart the code
                else:
                    print("\nThanks For Playing :)")
                    exit()
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with the OP's code. This does not fix the issue, because the `dos` method recurses into itself until the correct number is guessed (or until the stack runs out of memory due to improper management). Thus, the game will continue until the user guesses the correct number or the program crashes and it has nothing to do with the number of guesses performed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

**1) Potential for infinite recursion**

```
Emo(100).uno()  # Restart the code
```

The above does not restart the code. It recursively calls the `uno()` method. It doesn't reinitialize anything and much worse - it takes up memory each time you call it because you are never returning from the function. If you want to restart, you should create a reset routine. Or you could simply initialize everything at the beginning of the routine and use a while loop.

**2) doesn't properly check against number of guesses**

```
        if number < com:
            print("Higher")
            self.dos()
        elif number > com:
            print("Lower")
            self.dos()
```

The above code is from the `dos()` method. This is another potential infinite recursion issue. While this routine does increment the `count` of guesses, it never checks against how many guesses occurred. It's going to keep calling itself recursively until either the user makes a correct guess or the program crashes from running out of memory. Nowhere is it actually checking to see if the user has made 5 guesses.

**3) Unnecessary complexity from duplicating logic across two functions**
There is no good reason for the `dos()` method at all. It is simply restating the logic of the `uno()` method, which adds unnecessary complexity and can lead to several of the issues you've observed. Define the code into a single body and look for repeating logic before defining a new function.

Here is a version of your code that addresses all of the concerns above.

```py
import random

class Emo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.com = random.randint(1, x)
        self.count = 0

    def uno(self):
        while True:
            win = False
            number = int(input(f"Guess a number between 1 and {self.x}: \n"))
            while self.count < 5:
                self.count += 1

                if number < self.com:
                    print("Higher")
                elif number > self.com:
                    print("Lower")
                else:
                    win = True
                    break

                if self.guess < 5:
                    number = int(input("Try Another One: \n"))

            if win:
                print("Correct!! You won..\n"
                        "\n"
                        "~旦_(^O^ )\n"
                        "")
            else:
                print("Game over")

            one_more = input("Want to play one more time? (e/h)\n")
            if one_more == "e":
                self.com = random.randint(1, self.x)
                self.count = 0
            else:
                print("\nThanks For Playing :)")
                break

Emo(100).uno()
```